# How can decrease the spacing between labels and inputs?

Tags: html, css, blazor, bootstrap-5, blazorise

I'm using Blazorise with Bootstrap 5, but I thought the space between the input and the label got too big.

Image space between the input and the label:

[image: Image space between the input and the label]

How can I decrease this spacing?

```
<Row>
  <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is2.OnTablet.Is1.OnFullHD">
    <Tooltip Text="Data de Fim" Placement="TooltipPlacement.Top">
      <FieldLabel TextColor="TextColor.Secondary">Inicio</FieldLabel>
      <DateEdit Style="width:150px" TextColor="TextColor.Primary" TValue="DateTime?" @bind-Date=Agenda.PeriodoInicial />
    </Tooltip>
  </Column>
  <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is2.OnTablet.Is1.OnFullHD">
    <Tooltip Text="Data de Fim" Placement="TooltipPlacement.Top">
      <FieldLabel TextColor="TextColor.Secondary">Fim</FieldLabel>
      <DateEdit Style="width:150px" TextColor="TextColor.Primary" TValue="DateTime?" @bind-Date=Agenda.PeriodoFinal />
    </Tooltip>
  </Column>
  <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is8.OnTablet" Class="form-check-inline">
    <FieldLabel TextColor="TextColor.Secondary">Periodo</FieldLabel>
    <RadioGroup TextColor="TextColor.Secondary" Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" TValue="int" Name="tipoPeriodo" @bind-CheckedValue=Agenda.TipoPeriodo>
      <Radio TextColor="TextColor.Primary" Inline="true" Value=0>Data Inicio</Radio>
      <Radio TextColor="TextColor.Secondary" Inline="true" Value=1>Data Liberação</Radio>
    </RadioGroup>
  </Column>
</Row>
```

Comment: in your browser, right click and inspect element. That will show you what selectors to use to control the margin/padding.

Answer (score 1):

blazorise already uses the form-label in its `Class` attribute.

**solution with css**

```
  <style>
        .form-label{
            margin-bottom:0px;
        }
    </style>
```

Result

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omq9d.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the CSS parameters for the Field Labels or Data elements.
e.g reduce margin-bottom on labels or add margin-top/padding top on the Data/field inputs.

You already have inline style attributes ( Style="width:150px" ) you can add the margin-top to these, although you would have to apply to each so I suggest declaring a CSS ID or Class on the field inputs to add the property change to all other elements.